Dropdown Data Not Displaying
I have a drop down that renders blank when clicked but when the page is resized or it is scrolled, then the data appears. It is attempting to load 2700 elements. I have another drop down that displays correctly but there is only 70 elements in that one. I get this warning when scrolled: "This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/scroll-linked_effects.html for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!" It seems like the bug is due to the number of elements that are attempting to display.
<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="margin-left:20px;">
                        <label>Provider (Total: <span id="provider-count"></span>):</label></br>
                        <select multiple id="doctorsDropdown" class="selectpicker" required data-live-search="true"
                            data-live-search-style="startsWith" data-actions-box="false" data-live-search-placeholder="Search">
                        </select>
                    </div>

function updateDataTable() 
        {
            var selectedDoctors = $('#doctorsDropdown').val();
            var selectedSpecialties = $('#specialtyDropdown').val();

            function appendParam(key, value) {
                if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
                    params.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
                }
            }

            var params = [];

            appendParam('doctors', selectedDoctors);
            appendParam('specialities', selectedSpecialties);

            var baseURL = './provider_report_data?' + params.join('&');

            if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dc-table-chart')) {
                $('#dc-table-chart').DataTable().clear().destroy();
            }
            initializeFirstTable(baseURL);
        }

$.ajax({
            url: './get_data_of_providers',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                const formattedData = data.map(item => {
                    const nameParts = item.full_name.split(' ');
                    const lastName = nameParts.pop();
                    const firstName = nameParts.join(' ');
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        full_name: lastName + ', ' + firstName,
                        last_name: lastName
                    };
                });

                formattedData.sort((a, b) => a.last_name.localeCompare(b.last_name));

                $('#doctorsDropdown').empty();
                $('#doctorsDropdown').append($('<optgroup>', {}).append($('<option>', {
                    value: '',
                    text: 'Deselect All'
                })));

                var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                formattedData.forEach(function (item) {
                    var doctorName = item.full_name;
                    if ('{{sensitiveMode}}' === 'true' && providerMapping[doctorName]) {
                        doctorName = providerMapping[doctorName].fakeName;
                    }
                    var option = $('<option>', {
                        value: item.full_name,
                        text: doctorName
                    });
                    fragment.appendChild(option[0]);
                });

                $('#doctorsDropdown').append(fragment);
                $('#doctorsDropdown').selectpicker('refresh');
                
                // Optionally trigger resize if necessary
                $(window).trigger('resize');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Error loading doctor details:', error);
            }
        });

$('#doctorsDropdown').on('change', function () {
            const containerId = $(this).attr('id');
            deselectAllOptions(containerId);
            updateDataTable();
});

I have tried to automatically scroll or resize the page but that is a band-aid instead of a fix.
Picture of the unrendered dropdown
